# Magento FME Layered Navigation with product count on attribute

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, layered-navigation

I installed FME Layered Navigation with AJAX but the module doesn't have a count next to the attribute. My question is, how can I make this happen?

I tried to insert this code in filter_attribute.phtml but it gives me fatal error

```
(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_item->getQty()` instead.

Comment: Are you able to provide error message and stacktrace?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCount() on a non-object in /app/design/frontend/skin/theme/template/layerednav/filter_attribute.phtml on line 8

Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 244

Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Session.php on line 88

Comment: Check those two php files and debug them going deeper in structure. This might be also related to some bad implementation of this module (mostly happens when there's some mistake in config.xml). Next things to do: clear cache and sessions in /var folder, check your server error log, and you might be running out of space or memory (based on informations from some threads)